# Code128 Barcode Generator

Tags: php, barcode

I am using code128 bar-code generator for generating bar-code in oscommerce site. If I am passing serial number of 19 digits (example : NJUGFRTUIVCD4567889) ,bar-code generates in correct format. But If the digits exceeds 20 , then bar-code is not generating in correct format. The text under bar-code will disappear.

What might be the problem for this. I changed width and height of barcode. But of no use.
Any help...

Comment: Which library are you using ? Have you tried to check which part is responsible for generating it ? If so maybe you can provide us the *core* of it ? And maybe just limit the characters to 19 ?

Comment: I am using BarCode library.There is no limit to the characters.

Comment: @philomine can you share the code, by which you are trying to generate barcode
Meanwhile if you want only 128 barcode use this https://github.com/anigenero/PHP-Barcode-Generator/blob/master/barcode.php
its helpful and don't break.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by the limitation of integer length. A [signed 64bit integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) can only contain 19 digits. You should keep it as a string or chose another data type which allows more than 19 digits.